# Invalid types error when creating more than one "char*" variable in the same line

Tags: python, string, char, cython

With the following function in Cython 0.19.1:

```
cdef dot(int m, int n, int k, char* transa='N', char* transb='N'):
    cdef char* check_transa='N', check_transb='N'
    if(transa==check_transa):
        lda = m
    else:
        lda = k
    if(transb==check_transb):
        ldb = k
    else:
        ldb = n
    ldc = m
```

I got the error:

```
Invalid types for '==' (char *, char)
```

But just putting the variable declaration in two lines like:

```
cdef char* check_transa='N'
cdef char* check_transb='N'
```

made it work...

Is it a bug or supposed to work in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how C (and by extension Cython) type declarations have always worked.  The line

```
char *a, b;
```

declares `a` as a `char *`, while `b` will be a `char`.  To declare two character pointers, you can also werite

```
char *a, *b;
```

but I recommend getting into the habit of using separate lines, which tends to be less error-prone.